# can I use xeditable with $resource?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Is there a way to use an angularjs $resource with x-editable remote validation?  I'm trying to avoid building a one off $http method since I already have a resource that does pretty much the same thing.

```
$scope.checkName = function(data) {
  var d = $q.defer();
  $http.post('/checkName', {value: data}).success(function(res) {
    res = res || {};
    if(res.status === 'ok') { // {status: "ok"}
      d.resolve()
    } else { // {status: "error", msg: "Username should be `awesome`!"}
      d.resolve(res.msg)
    }
  }).error(function(e){
    d.reject('Server error!');
  });
  return d.promise;
};
```